# WordPress Coding And Content Excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've written a function to handle excerpts but just for the front page.

```
http://stevefleming.co.uk/
```

And the function is...

```
function excerpt_filter2($limit) {

$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
$excerpt = explode(' ', $content, $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt) . "...&nbsp;<a href='". get_permalink(the_ID()) ."'> continue reading</a>";
} else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
}
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
echo $excerpt;
}
```

The problem, as you can see on the front page, is that it keeps appending the post id to the front of the text.

I've tried to debug the code and dumped the $excerpt array just before the implode is called to check that the id wasn't somehow being placed in the array... it wasn't.

I'm at a loss as to how the post id is getting there.

Any ideas?

Steve

Comment: `the_ID` -> `get_the_ID`

Answer (score 2):

The function `the_ID()` automatically outputs the result. Change this line:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt) . "...&nbsp;<a href='". get_permalink(the_ID()) ."'> continue reading</a>";
```

To:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt) . "...&nbsp;<a href='". get_permalink(get_the_ID()) ."'> continue reading</a>";
```

Check out [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) for more info, Wordpress usually has an alternate function that won't output the result in the form: `get_*`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple :)

Answer (score 0):

your code here

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt) . "...&nbsp;<a href='". get_permalink(the_ID()) ."'> continue reading</a>";
```

you are using

```
the_ID()
```

that will ech the id f the post so try to change it to

```
get_the_ID()
```

hope this is what you are facing. :) cheers

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom just pipped you to the post but I do appreciate it.